# replace characters in url by gene/compound id using python

Tags: python, replace, char, int, python-3.5

I am trying to replace part of url by gene id using python 3.5. Can someone help me in replacing 'xxx' by integer stored in variable input_id?

```
input_id = 135
my_url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
my_url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/xxx"
input_id = 135
print my_url.replace("xxx",str(input_id))

o/p: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/135
```

Comment: it doesn't let me add integer to string

Comment: yes there is a way can you wait till i reconstruct my code please thank you

Comment: I am getting error 'Can't convert int object to str implicitly'

Comment: Try and let me know if it works. And please vote up if it's helpful thank you :)

Comment: Bingo! @hiren jungi thats very helpful. Happy thursday

Comment: glad to help buddy :) please vote up happy thursday as well have a good day